# C# - How can I check if DateTime has time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I validate if a give DateTime has actual time not just the default midnight time (00:00:00).

```
DateTime.TryParse("2022-11-01T14:52:17", out DateTime withTime1); // has time
DateTime.TryParse("2022-11-01T00:00:01", out DateTime withTime2); // has time
DateTime.TryParse("2022-11-01T00:00:00", out DateTime noTime ); // doesn't have time
```

Comment: `dt.Equals(dt.Date)`

Comment: Specifically "has time *which is not midnight*"?  All three of these (string) values "have a time".

Comment: Why are you asking about `DateTime` values and showing `strings`?

Comment: cause it's easier to visualize the actual time than if I would instantiate the same datetime using DateTime()...

Comment: FYI, the default time *is* an actual time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of what you posted are `DateTime` values. They are `strings`. I'll answer the question you actually asked though:

```cs
if (myDateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    // Time is midnight.
}
else
{
    // Time is not midnight.
}
```

Comment: For string value chcek, can add a little complexity to the condition: `bool hasTime = DateTime.TryParse(withTime1, out testTime) && testTime == DateTime.MinValue ? false: testTime.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Zero;`

Answer (score 0):

From your example it depends if you want to verify that as a string or not

as a string you could do something like this

```
if(Datetime.toString().Split('T')[1] == "00:00:00")
    return false; //"no time" per your explanation
else
    return true; //time
```